# Cartoon episode where the heroes (a dude and a blue skinned/haired alien girl) are inside a robot and have to destroy it from the inside to get out

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon, robots

I have this very old memory of an episode from a cartoon where our two heroes, a human guy and a blue alien girl, are inside of a giant robot which is hunting them and they have to react a part of it to destroy it. At the end there is a scene with the damaged robot walking towards the sunset and malfunctioning. The only additional thing i remember from this is that it made me scared cause of the feeling of being so tiny in comparison to something hunting you. I'd appreciate any help cause I haven't found anything for the longest time

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: *Ulysses 31* was a cartoon with a human boy (Telemachus) and a blue-skinned alien girl (Yumi); I'm not sure if there was an episode with them inside a robot, but certainly they were hunted by robots at various points.